# Sums of binomial random variables, approximately normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Twelve statisticians arrive at a village with only four hotels. The number of free beds $N_i,$ for $i = 1, \dots, 4$ available in each hotel $i$ has Binomial distribution $N_i \sim \mathsf{Bin}(30; 0.2),$ independently of each other.

(a) What is the probability that there will not be enough beds for all twelve statisticians? 
*Hint:* you may use a continuous approximation to the Binomial distribution.

(b) What is the probability all twelve statisticians will be able to stay in the same hotel?
*Hint:* Again, you may use a continuous approximation.

The question for part a) I solved it with normal distribution and get the correct answer 0.002. But I am not sure how to deal with part b), do I still use the normal distribution to solve it? How?

Comment: I have edited your question for format. There were some ambiguities. Please make corrections if the meaning is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will have already found working part (a),
$\mu = E(N_i) = 6,\,\sigma^2 = Var(N_i) = 4.8,$ and $\sigma = SD(N_i) = \sqrt{4.8} = 2.191.$

Thus the probability that the $i$th hotel can accommodate all 12 statisticians
is
$$P(N_i \ge 12) = P(N_i > 11.5) = P\left(\frac{N_i - \mu}{\sigma } > \frac{11.5 -6}{2.191} \right) \approx P(Z > 2.51) = 0.0060,$$
according to the normal approximation to the binomial distribution, with continuity correction.

With software or a statistical calculator, it is easy to find the exact
binomial probability $P(N_i \ge 12) = 0.0095.$

```
sum(dbinom(12:30,30,.2))  # 'dbinom' is PDF
## 0.009493122            # P(N=12) + P(N=13) + ... + P(N=30)
1 - pbinom(11, 30, .2)    # 'pbinom' is CDF
## 0.009493122            # 1 - P(N <= 11)
```

You were given permission to use the normal approximation for part (b).
That does not guarantee that the approximation is accurate. [Nowadays, when
software is readily available to find exact binomial probabilities, it seems
unsatisfying to use 'borderline' normal approximations.]

Whichever, value of $P(N_i \ge 12)$ you prefer (0.0060 or 0.0095), you can use it to get the answer to part (b). What is the probability that no one hotel has
enough rooms for all 12 statisticians?

---

The plot below shows exact binomial probabilities as bars and the approximating
normal density function as a blue curve. $P(N_i \ge 12)$ is the probability
to the right of the vertical red line. (Negligible values above 20 are not shown.)
[image]

---

*Note:* If you are familiar with R statistical software, you may get
some insights by looking at the following simulation for a million
hypothetical villages. (With a million iterations, most answers are correct to two or three places.)

```
n = 30;  p=.2
n1 = rbinom(m, 30, .2)
mean(n1);  n*p
## 5.997915                         # aprx E(N[1])
## 6                                # exact
sd(n1);  sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
## 2.187973                         # aprx SD(N[1])
## 2.19089                          # exact
n2 = rbinom(m, 30, .2)
n3 = rbinom(m, 30, .2)
n4 = rbinom(m, 30, .2)
t = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4
mean(t);  4*n*p
## 24.00078                          # aprx E(T)
## 24                                # exact
sd(t);  sqrt(4*n*p*(1-p))
## 4.37463                           # aprx SD(T)
## 4.38178                           # exact
mean(t < 12)                         # (t < 12) has 10^6 TRUEs and FALSEs
## 0.001037                          # aprx P(Insufficient hotel rooms in village)
mean(n1>=12 | n2 >= 12 | n3 >=12 | n4 >= 12)   # '|' means 'OR'
## 0.037263                          # aprx P(Enough rooms at some one hotel)
1 - mean(n1<12)*mean(n2<12)*mean(n3<12)*mean(n4<12)
## 0.03729869                        # alternate aprx for (b)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the right answer for part b) is 0.024......

Comment: Your 'right' answer is from $1 - (1-.006)^4 = 0.0238.$ But 0.006 is incorrect normal approx. So the actual right answer is $1-(1-.0095)^4 = 0.0375,$ based on the true value of $P(N_i \ge 12) = 0.9995$ and confirmed to three places by the value 0.037 in the simulation. // Because the book says to use norm. approx., you shouldn't argue with the answ given there--for purposes of your course. But you should be aware that the normal approx of BINOM(30,.2) is _very sketchy_ as shown by the figure. // I do make mistakes, but I think not this time.